# Best way to upload around 500+ images (small to 4k size) using NodeJs from an Angular 8 app?

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, multipartform-data, multer

We have an Angular 8 application where User can manage his Images. each User can select around 500+ images (small to 4k in size) in the App and then he can upload it to the NodeJs server.

So My concern is like these 500+ images can have large size and I don't know that NodeJs server can process this amount of images or not because there will be other Users as well who will be uploading same amount of Images.

So My question is like How we can make this entire functionality or process more user friendly with better optimisation?

I'm literally curious about the Answer so I welcome each and every suggestion and the Solution.

Comment: You can use AWS's s3 bucket where your image will be stored in cloud so that your node server won't be over weighted. There is Aws SDK for node available.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for you suggestion, actually we need to process the images in the NodeJs server so it's mandatory to upload there.

Comment: We do something similar to that. From Angular user uploads image. Image stores in s3 bucket and I'll be storing the image key in MongoDB with Node API. When I need to process the image I write node API to get image from s3 bucket and process in node js.